# Add a column with value containing in certain column's value

Tags: loops, join

Really hope to get some help as I already f-d my brain out in trying to achieve it.

I have a DataFrame:

```
    PagePath                        Source
0   /product/123/sometext           (Other)
1   /product/234?someutminfo        (Other)
2   /product/112?whatever       (Other)
```

A aslo have another dataframe with short product paths:

```
    Path           Other stuff
0   /product/123   Foo
1   /product/234   Bar
2   /product/345   Buzz
3   /product/456   Lol
```

What I need is to create a new column in first df that will match the second df so that it will contain short Paths if there are ones.

So far I managed to do the following:

1) Created a series from the second df by subsetting it

2) Sort of iterated through the first df with list from the second

```
df1['newcol'] = df1['PagePath'].str.contains('|'.join(list_from_df2))
```

Which gave me a column with True/False based on whether match was found.

I understand that what I need to do is to iterate through each row from first df, iterate through each value of list and return it when the match is found.
 But if only could I write an appropriate code for it. I really hope for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem myself:

First we define a function:

```
def return_match(row):
    try:
        return re.search(r'/product/.+-\d+/', row).group(0)
    except:
        return 'Not a product'
```

Then we apply a funcgion over a necessary column:

```
df['newcol'] = df['PagePath'].apply(return_match)
```